# Spring Security v6.0 whitelist endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to whitelist login and register endpoints from going through JWTRequestFilter using permitAll(); method however all the requests are going through it.

```
package com.ecommerce.ecommerce.security;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JWTRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, AuthorizationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests((auth)  -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login", "/api/v1/auth/register")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}
```

I have tried to whitlist it using web.ignoring() method however still not working and also I learned that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated and not available anymore in Spring Security 6.0 as suggested in some old threads.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 6 you need two security filter chains, one configured to respond only to your whitelisted endpoints and another as a catch-all for your authenticated endpoints. Only the catch-all will add the jwt request filter to the chain.

Here's the outline, adapt to your needs:

```java
@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfiguration {

  // whitelist
  @Bean
  @Order(0)
  public SecurityFilterChain whitelistFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    String[] endpoints = new String[] {"/api/v1/auth/login", "/api/v1/auth/register"};
    
    return http
      .securityMatcher(endpoints)
      // add other calls on the HttpSecurity object
      .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(endpoints).permitAll())
      .build();
  }

  // catch-all
  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain catchAllFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
      .addFilter(yourAuthFilter)
      // add other calls on the HttpSecurity object
      .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
      .build();
  }
}
```

The key here is that the first security filter chain to be evaluated with `@Order(0)` has a `securityMatcher` call that opts-in to only the matched endpoints. This approach is better than the old `web.ignoring()` method because you can still make use of Spring's CSRF and XSS protection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

> 

```
 @AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JWTRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login", "/api/v1/auth/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: The **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class does not exist anymore since Spring Security  5.7 and also the .and() method so this way is deprecated however thanks for considering my question .